# How can I get Carrier and IP Address and Device Id on J2ME?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, nokia

How can I get **Carrier** and **IP Address** and **Device Id** on J2ME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to get these information on JavaME however on Nokia platforms there are some [Nokia specific system properties](http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-A1F90B63-5F14-4829-BCA1-A23B925CF670.html) that you can use. *com.nokia.mid.imsi* and *com.nokia.mid.networkid* may be interesting for your case.

For the IP address I suggest that you use a server side call to retrieve the IP address from referrer.

Comment: For many years, development is done; still there isn't any standart library for these .